# Need Extjs editorgrid store to queue up remove/delete events and fire them later

Tags: extjs, destroy, jsonstore

I have a form where the user can remove notes from an order.  I do not want the notes store to call the destroy url with the deleted notes unless the user clicks the save button.  Should I be able to call suspendEvents(true) on the store and then call resumeEvents later, when the user clicks save, and have it post to the destroy url for all of the deleted notes?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be to privately maintain a collection of data containing the necessary info for the notes you want to destroy.  You can hook the 'afteredit' event to append to this collection for later destroying.

After that, all you'd need to do is add a toolbar button to the grid that has a handler attached to actually pass the collection data to your server and clear out your collection of notes to destroy.

Hope this helps, although I might be misunderstanding what you are attempting to accomplish as your description is a little tough to fully wrap my head around.

Comment: What you suggested is what I am going to end up doing.  I thought there should be a way to get the store to send the ajax request to the server to do all of that for me - especially since it seems to have all the data and to be listening for the correct events so that it could already do all of that for me, if it were coded that way.

Answer (score 0):

Set the autoSave:false config option on the store, then every time a user removes a note from the order, just call store.remove(noteRecord) -- when the user clicks the save button, call store.save() and all modified records will be sent to the server (assuming you have a writer configured for the store)